# Having trouble connecting my CustomCell.xib to my tableView in the storyboard

Tags: ios, swift

I Have to do an app for recipes and it shows me different recipes in my tableView, and i just want to implement my CustomCell (from a xib file) to my storyboard and I don't know how to connect it to show my data (I already checked my identifier) here's the code of my controller :

```
class SearchRecipe: UIViewController, ShowAlert {

var recipeData = RecipeDataModel()
var recipe = [String]()


@IBOutlet weak var tableViewSearch: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.tableViewSearch.rowHeight = 130
}

func updateRecipeData(json: JSON){

    if let ingredients = json["hits"][0]["recipe"]["ingredientLines"].arrayObject{

        recipeData.ingredientsOfRecipe = ingredients[0] as! String
        recipeData.cookingTime = json["hits"][0]["recipe"]["totalTime"].stringValue
        recipeData.recipe = json["hits"][0]["recipe"]["label"].stringValue
        recipeData.recipeImage = json["hits"][0]["recipe"]["image"].stringValue

    }
    else {
        print("Problem")
    }
    //self.tableViewSearch.reloadData()
   }
}
extension SearchRecipe: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return recipe.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customRecipeCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomRecipeCell
    getRecipesDisplay(in: cell, from: recipeData , at: indexPath)
    return cell
}


func getRecipesDisplay(in cell: CustomRecipeCell, from recipeModel: RecipeDataModel, at indexPath: IndexPath){

    cell.recipeTitle.text = recipeData.recipe
    cell.recipeInfos.text = recipeData.ingredientsOfRecipe
    cell.timerLabel.text = recipeData.cookingTime
  }   
}
```

and this is the code my xib file :

```
class CustomRecipeCell: UITableViewCell {


@IBOutlet weak var recipeTitle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var recipeInfos: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var cellImageBackground: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var likeAndTimerView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var likeImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var timerImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var likeLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var timerLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    activityIndicator.isHidden = true
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
  }
}
```

Comment: you have to register your `nib` for `tableView` in a `viewDidLoad`: `yourTableView.register(nib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: identifier)`: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-register-a-cell-for-uitableviewcell-reuse

Comment: I added this in my viewDidLoad but still nothing : tableViewSearch.register(CustomRecipeCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "customRecipeCell")

Comment: If you are using a storyboard why are you using XIB files for your cells?  Why not just use prototype cells in the storyboard?  That way all of the cell registration is done for you.

Comment: Well Paul I tried to do via the storyboard but didn't managed to do it... so I'm with xib file..

Answer (score 0):

In ViewDidLoad, you must register your cell this way:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  tableViewSearch.register(UINib(nibName:" /* NAME OF YOUR XIB FILE */ ", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "customRecipeCell")
}
```

You also have to edit the size of your cell in the attribute inspector of your custom cell and of your table view